# CSV to Data Table is removing primary keys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv

I'm loading a CSV file into a Data table.  The file is loading successfully, however, it's removing some of the primary keys in the first column.  It's removing all the values with a letter in it. I noticed it's treating them string vs numbers.  I set the cell type for the column to text, but it didn't make a difference, as I would expect with a CSV file.

Here's how I'm loading the file.

```
    public static DataTable GetDataFromCSV(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader)
    {
        string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";
        string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + filename + "]";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
        {
                using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    return dataTable;
                }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this.

[image]

It should be this.

[image]

Comment: Yikes. This is a very heavy solution for CSV in .NET. Have you tried any of the several native libs?

Comment: I haven't, would you have any suggestions on what to try? My issue is that there are many results for 1 key.  I need to combine all the results to 1 row based on a timestamp (october, november, december) columns

Comment: Try to add IMEX=1 to the extended properties in your connection string but I'm not sure if that will work for a CSV. Another possibility is to use [Schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx) file, there you can specify all kinds of things like column data types and more.